# Different binding approach at each level of Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I've generated an **XDocument** at code behind as below:

```
<Root>
  <Pubs>
    <Book id='A123'>
      <Author state='AS'>Moreno</Author>
    </Book>
    <Book id='B456'>
      <Author state='BS'>Gazit</Author>
    </Book>
  </Pubs>
</Root>
```

and want to bind this to a **Treeview** control in **WPF** application to have something like this:

```
+ Pubs              //Pubs Element Name
  + A123            //Book Element Attribute Value
    + Moreno        //Author Element Inner text
  + B456
    + Gazit
```

so, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Is the Answer:

**For each Level of TreeView** we must define a specific`HierarchicalDataTemplate` in `TreeView.Resources` with:

1. `DataType` = element name
2. `ItemsSource` = binding child name

for example as below:

```
  <TreeView Name="treeView2"   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Root.Elements}">
            <TreeView.Resources>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Book" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" x:Key="template1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path='Attribute[id].Value'}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Pubs" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}" x:Key="template2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path='Name'}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="Author" x:Key="template3">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path='Attribute[state].Value'}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

and everything is ok!

Answer (score 4):

You should deserialize each of these elements into a proper object, and then build a tree hierarchy out of observable collections.

You should read about WPF TreeView using MVVM. This tutorial is pretty good -

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TreeViewWithViewModel.aspx

Comment: This tutorial is not about different binding approach for each level!

Comment: No, it is a tutorial about different templates for each level. In the second demo you can see that each level has different Icons, and that multiple templates had been defined. A HierarchicalDataTemplate  has been defined for RegionViewModel,StateViewModel and CityViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

Defining in your (control or window or application) resources a DataTemplate having Book as DataType, and binding a TreeView to your list of Book might do the job.

Comment: What about 'Pubs' and 'Author' Elements? Is there any code sample!?